# I Want to show only mosques near to my current location Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, listview

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {


    GoogleMap map;
    private boolean flag = true;
    private ProgressDialog mainDialog;
    private MarkerOptions mp; ///my point




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);






        mainDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Wait a bit", "...", true);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mainDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We are not allow to take your current location.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        final LatLng MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (flag && location != null) {
            map.clear();
            mp = new MarkerOptions();
            mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            mp.title("my position");
            map.addMarker(mp);
           // map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10));
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(MOUNTAIN_VIEW)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                .zoom(10)                   // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            mainDialog.dismiss();
           new getMosque().execute(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));


        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                new getMosque().execute(mp.getPosition());
                break;
        }
        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    class getMosque extends AsyncTask<LatLng, String, LatLng> {

        double x, y;
        String name;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private LatLng myPoint;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected LatLng doInBackground(LatLng... params) {

            myPoint = params[0];

            String s = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch" +
                    "/json?location=" + myPoint.latitude + "," + myPoint.longitude
                    + "&radius=50000&types=mosque&name=ireland" +
                    "&key=AIzaSyDP_2efAut2LHEHU4xc6_oe-1Yf-x-EKKA";

            Log.i("app", s);

            try {


                URL url = new URL(s);
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()).getInputStream()));
                JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement jsonElement = jp.parse(r);
                JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                Log.i("app", "doInBackground: json = " + jsonObject.toString());
                JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("results");
                for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {
                name = element.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();


                        if (name.contains("Islamic Cultural Centre of Ireland")) {
                            x = Double.valueOf(element.getAsJsonObject().get("geometry").getAsJsonObject().get("location").getAsJsonObject().get("lat").getAsString());

                            //Log.i("app", "doInBackground: x = " + x);

                            y = Double.valueOf(element.getAsJsonObject().get("geometry").getAsJsonObject().get("location").getAsJsonObject().get("lng").getAsString());

                            break;
                        }
                    }



                    return new LatLng(x, y);


            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LatLng latLng) {
            super.onPostExecute(latLng);
            dialog.dismiss();



            MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
            mp.position(latLng);
            mp.title(name);
            mp.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.masjid));
            map.addMarker(mp);
            flag = false;


            if (latLng != null) {

                mp.position(latLng);
                mp.title(name);
                mp.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.masjid));
                map.addMarker(mp);
                flag = false;


            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, but we didn't find any embassy near you.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }



    }

}
```

[this image show json parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g2OW.png)

[function to getmosque near to my current location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrG6q.png)

Hi all my question is about to get point of interest from my current location. In my case i am trying to find mosques near to my current location. i have added two images to explain how i am trying to get mosques from my current location. I am able to show my current location and also i am able to show on mosque using (if else)statement. I am using json to get all the mosques but i am able to show only one. i want to show all the mosques near to me from json. please help me to sort out this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: ok let me try thanks

Comment: i added the code can you please have a look thanks

Comment: I don't know if this will fix it, but you have a `for` loop with a return statement. That way, the for loop will only run one time. Line containing `for (JsonElement element : jsonArray) {`.

Answer (score 0):

Radius and variables

```
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 5000;
```

onLocationChange Method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    //mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


    String Mosque = "mosque";


        Log.d("onClick", "Button is Clicked");
        mMap.clear();

        String url = getUrl(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude(), Mosque);
        Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
        DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
        DataTransfer[1] = url;
        Log.d("onClick", url);
        GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
        getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);


    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

Here is the getUrl Method:

```
    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

    StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + nearbyPlace);
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
    googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyBt7_eLLSV66gAbwMPvv8bqp5b9QklPYzc");
    Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop contains a break, which breaks out of the for loop after the first iteration, so you are able to display only 1 record.